# Use variables from a class in another script

Tags: python

Basically, I need to store some variables in a script and use them in another:

###### stored_variables.py

```
class Setup():
    def setup():
        a = 'X'

        if a == 'X':
            #Credentials for X
            database = 'a'
            user = 'b'
            password = 'c'
            host = 'd'
            port = 4
        
        elif a == 'Y':
            #Credentials for Y
            database = 'x'
            user = 'y'
            password = 'z'
            host = 'w'
            port = 7
```

and then use the specific variables based on the "if" statement in my second script that looks like this:

###### connection.py

```
class Connection:
    def __init__(self, host, database, port, user, password):   
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
            database=database,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            host=host,
            port=port
        )
```

Comment: credentials in code doesn't look safe, store them in a seperate file, like a config or .yaml file idealy encrypted. If you dont care about that you can put them in a dictionary and initialize it by the __ init __ method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store those infos in the code!
That said, if you really want to:

```
class Setup:
    def __init__(self):
        # have those loaded as a encrypted config rather than stored in code!
        self.cfg = {'x': {'database': 'a', 'user': 'b'},
                    'y': {'database': 'b', 'user': 'c'}}
    
    def setup(self, user):
        return self.cfg.get(user)
        
i_setup = Setup()

database, user = i_setup.setup('y').values()
print(database, user)
# b c
```

---

Now you can import this class in the other file and initialize it there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance for the first Class (Setup) and then, consume variables.

```
s = setup()
c = connection (s.host,s.username...)
```